# How to plot scatter plot and line graph on same graph using google charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, data-visualization

I have some stock data like so

```
index=[1,2,3,4,5]
price=[10,11,12,13,14]
```

I have to plot a line graph of this data using google-Visualization and highlight (or scatter) some points on the line. the points are for example:

```
index=[1,3]
value=[11,13]
```

I have the following code rightnow

```
function drawChart() {

// Create the data table.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number',"index");
data.addColumn("number",'price')
data.addRows([
  [1, 10],
  [2, 11],
  [3, 12],
  [4, 13],
  [5, 14]
]);

// Set chart options
var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
               'width':1200,
               'height':300, hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'},
               slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:80},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0},
      explorer: { 
        actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
        axis: 'horizontal',
        keepInBounds: true,
        maxZoomIn: 4.0},
      colors: ['#D44E41'],};

// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);

//Initailization
google.charts.load('current', {
      callback: drawChart,
      packages:['corechart']
    });
```

example image of result I want (the graph is not plotted on the values in the question)[image]

Comment: No actually I want some some line points to be highlighted on the graph. please find the attached image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to highlight individual points, you have a couple options.

**1)** use a [style](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole)  column role

the style column role allows you to apply a style to individual values in the data table.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'index');
data.addColumn('number', 'price')
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'})
data.addRows([
  [1, 10, null],
  [2, 11, 'point { size: 8; fill-color: #a52714; }'],
  [3, 12, null],
  [4, 13, null],
  [5, 14, null]
]);
```

in the data table, the style column should immediately follow the series to by styled.
when using a line chart, you must give the `pointSize` option a positive value,
in order for the point to be visible.

e.g. `pointSize: 0.1`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'index');
  data.addColumn('number', 'price')
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'})
  data.addRows([
    [1, 10, null],
    [2, 11, 'point { size: 4; fill-color: #a52714; }'],
    [3, 12, null],
    [4, 13, null],
    [5, 14, null]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
    width: 1200,
    height: 300,
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Year',
      titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'},
      slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle:80
    },
    vAxis: {
      minValue: 0
    },
    explorer: {
      actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
      axis: 'horizontal',
      keepInBounds: true,
      maxZoomIn: 4.0
    },
    colors: ['#D44E41'],
    pointSize: 0.1,
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**2)** add another series and change the series type to scatter.

first, add another column to the data table for the second series.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'index');
data.addColumn('number', 'price')
data.addColumn('number', 'point')
data.addRows([
  [1, 10, null],
  [2, 11, 11],
  [3, 12, null],
  [4, 13, null],
  [5, 14, null]
]);
```

in the options, use the `series` option to change the series type.
you can also hide the series from the legend, if needed.

```
series: {
  1: {
    type: 'scatter',
    visibleInLegend: false
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'index');
  data.addColumn('number', 'price')
  data.addColumn('number', 'point')
  data.addRows([
    [1, 10, null],
    [2, 11, 11],
    [3, 12, null],
    [4, 13, null],
    [5, 14, null]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
    width: 1200,
    height: 300,
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Year',
      titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'},
      slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle:80
    },
    vAxis: {
      minValue: 0
    },
    explorer: {
      actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
      axis: 'horizontal',
      keepInBounds: true,
      maxZoomIn: 4.0
    },
    colors: ['#D44E41', '#a52714'],
    series: {
      1: {
        type: 'scatter',
        visibleInLegend: false
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: it helped...Insane :)

Comment: note: wasn't sure if i followed exactly, but if you want all points to be seen on the line, just simply set option --> `pointSize: 4` -- or any other size...

Comment: No I just want some points to be shown on graph which are in `index` and `value` arrays and you rocked :)